# OutOfMemoryError in my gridAdapter

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, adapter

I'm trying create adapter for my gridView which should contains photo, which I chose  in gallery. But I have following OutOfMemoryError in line "return row"

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<String> images_urls;

public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<String> images_urls) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, images_urls);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.images_urls = images_urls;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

     File f = new File(images_urls.get(position));  
     Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
     holder.image.setImageURI(imageUri);
    return row;
}


static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
}
}
```

And I just don't know what makes error. Could someone help me solve it?

Comment: create thumbnails instead put the image on memory

Answer (score 1):

Image loading is a way way more complex thema than this, if you're interested on it, there's lots of topics/blog/etc you can read online. But StackOverflow is a direct question-answer, so,

To fix the issue, import this library: https://github.com/square/picasso

and then replace those lines:

```
File f = new File(images_urls.get(position));  
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
holder.image.setImageURI(imageUri);
```

with:

```
Picasso
  .with(holder.image.getContext())
  .load(image_urls.get(position))
  .into(holder.image);
```

this library will take care of proper managing the memory. Make sure to further check the library API as you can put extra commands to resize the image on-screen so it uses less memory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I'd like to use Picasso as you desribed but my GridView doesn't show any image. Could problem be in setting of my layout? I have wrap_content in my ImageView. Because when I change heap size (as it was mentioned in answer below), without Picasso, it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

In Your **AndroidManifest.xml**

add **android:largeHeap="true"** to your < application >

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.sample.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And to avoid OutofMemory Error you should use Universal Image Loader [Link](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) or Picasso Library [Link](https://github.com/square/picasso).